# how to manually download and install streamsets data collector destination packages

Tags: apache-kafka, streamsets

Does anyone know of a way to download and install destination packages for Streamsets Data Collector. My SDC does not have access to the internet hence why I cannot do it the standard panel way.

I specifically want to download the kafka package and manually install it in Streamsets Data Collector.

Answer (score 1):

Figure it out.

I used a local VM to install the desired package (Kafka in this case). Then went to the streamset-libs folder, tar zcvf the kafka package folder there and copied that to the streamsets server with no internet access. After restarting the streamsets instance there the Kafka destination appeared. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can download the full tarball from https://streamsets.com/opensource/, and choose 'Full Tarball'.
Those are usable for 'offline' install.
In case you need to add more modules, plugins, etc, you can download it and install it in addition to the current install.
I have offline SDC running somewhere, and have not tried adding more modules into it (yet)